# XPS-13-7390, Ubuntu 20.04 fingerprint Scanner Support

Tags: xps

I bought the XPS before 20.04 was released after the upgrade the fingerprint scanner disapeard , i think dell dropped some hardware support cause the repos were disabled, the fingerprint scanner didnt work on 18.04 either but the option was there. Did anybody found a solution to this?

cheerz